# How do I get the next year?

Tags: templating, datetime

I can get the current year in this way:

```
{% set currentYear = now.year %}
```

How do I get the next year?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{% set nextYear = now|date_modify('+1 year')|date('Y') %}
```

Comment: You're too fast, Christian.

Comment: Brandon's answer is great if you're only adjusting the year (as the original question asks). But if any adjustments need to be made to the month or day, this answer would work better.

Answer (score 11):

You can also get it with:

```
{% set nextYear = now.year + 1 %}
```

Comment: It is really simplier! (best) But I won't unaccept first answer in order not to be rude.

Comment: No arguments there! Christian’s is a good answer too – certainly more flexible, and something that could be done with “pure Twig” (the `.year` property is only actually available in Craft’s extended DateTime class).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! For the future: If I am not an autor of a post, I don't get notified if you comment, so you should add @nicael.

Comment: @nicael Nice, I didn’t know SE had @ mention support.

Comment: Now I got notified. All right! =)

Comment: Which makes the better answer if the question itself doesn't imply a preference for succinctness vs. flexibility?

Comment: I read somewhere that you can only notify users in the same "comments thread". Too bad, a @Brandon could come handy in deserted questions! :)

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach that's what bounties are for ;)